# How to show Last Login Date in SalesForce.com

Tags: date, authentication, salesforce

I want to show last login date on my site template page, how to do that?
I tried to use {!$User.LastLoginDate}, but it says "Field LastLoginDate does not exist. Check spelling".

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this field is not exposed through the $User global variable. You could expose a date property in your page controller and query for the with SOQL.

```
public DateTime lastlogin{get;set;}

controller: 
User u = [SELECT LastLoginDate FROM User WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
lastlogin = u.LastLoginDate;


VF: {! lastlogin }
```

Comment: @Sanjivani You can also select my answer as such by clicking the V icon under the upvote/downvote thingies. This will indicate to other users this question has been resolved.